# prerequisites before running sap business one

Tags: windows-7, accounting, sap

What processes should run on the background before I try to launch sap business one?
I'm just a beginner and I need to create a new company before I can make use of sap. The problem is I can't create one because I'm having difficulties with the server which is on my computer. I've installed sql server 2005. But I'm using a sap business one application which is just mounted from a vhd file.
Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I really need to learn how to use this application since were going to create a point of sale system. Using it would give me an idea what to include in the system that were going to make.

Comment: Trying to get a SAP stack exchange started, check it out http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41621/sap-systems-applications-and-products